# Is there a "brainwallet" for GPG keys?

Tags: pgp, password-based-encryption

“Brainwallet” is a program that takes a passphrase (hopefully a good one) and deterministically creates a Bitcoin wallet. This wallet can be used for transactions, then deleted from the computer. To get access to the wallet again, you only need the passphrase to re-create it.

Does something similar exist for GPG? If yes, where can I get it?
If not, is it even possible to create such a program? Maybe it's just a bad idea?

Comment: I don't know whether it exists in GPG in a standardized interface/format, but the answer to whether it is possible is yes. Private keys usually get seeded with random data, but you could also deterministically create private keys for GPG use from a password.

Comment: Same problem as for all password based encryption, except a bit worse since it's not possible to use salts. So whenever practical, encrypt your private key with the password instead of using a password as seed.

Comment: This shouldn’t be that difficult to made. All one need is crypto secure, password based,  deterministic "random" source.

Comment: @ralu The coding part is easy. Typical password quality is a problem, especially since you can't use salts.

Comment: This is why the salt for the passphrase is personally identifiable information such as name, social security number, DOB and such.  I am aware that it is possible. The question is how anyone done it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think the password quality isn't a problem. A 5 word passphrase would be solid. Really it is up to the user to pick something secure. Is there any software that can create the priv/pub from a passphrase instead of a random.

Comment: @RobKohr, you might personally *think* that password quality not a problem.... but in practice, it *is* a problem.  A 5-word passphrase might have entropy as low as 50 bits or lower.  That's not enough to resist off-line attack and would have security problems if you faced a serious motivated adversary.

Comment: I have done this.  See my code here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937369/can-i-create-a-reproducible-pgp-keypair-with-a-passphrase-using-bouncycastle-for

Comment: @figlesquidge, I don't know about that. How to generate a gpg key from a passphrase seems more crypto than security.

Comment: @CodesInChaos  How right you were. I created a bitcoin brain wallet with a seven word passphrase only to have those funds vanish off of it 2 days later.

Comment: My mistake, good point

Comment: @RobKohr If those were seven random independent words, this is a bit surprising, since I'd estimate that those have 80 bits of entropy or so, which should make it rather expensive to crack. If it was a quote from a book or movie, then they probably mined that source for quotes.